# Android Edittext display only part of inputted character

Tags: android

I'm having a  strange problem with  the android edittext inputfield.

I use the edittext field to let the user of an app answer questions that are generated by the app.
Now this works fine...but every now and again.. completely random (i.e. i could not find the pattern)  the edittext field stops displaying the input after **the first part of the first input character**. 
 To test I type in an incorrect answer to the question many times in a row. The problem occurs anywhere between the first and the 500th or so repetition of the wrong answer.  
 It's only a display issue because all the inputted characters can be retrieved  from the edittext field (with gettext() ).
I did not find this behaviour on my simulations only on my test phone (samsung galaxy s)
I could not find anything in the log...
The editfield is on a TabHost-tab. When i switch to another tab and return everything is fine again, the same applies to rotating the device to landscape and back. 
Did anybody ever encounter this strange behaviour  : edittext stops showing text after only part (looks like 1 or 2 leftmost pixels of the character) of the first inputted character..and can point me to a direction ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to do with the phone. I was testing one of my apps on a few phones, one of which was a Samsung Europa, and everyone once in a while, the text in the EditText went funny, and on very rare occasions, the EditText boxes didn't render properly. Like you said, changing to landscape and back fixes the problem but I think it's not a problem you can fix, just a problem with Samsung's product.